# Error generando clases con xsd

Tags: c#, vb.net, xml, aeat-sii

La Agencia Tributaria española (AEAT) ha publicado una serie de xsd para el nuevo sistema de Suministro Inmediato de Información (SII) que entrará en vigor a partir de Julio de 2017. En otras ocasiones como con la entrada en vigor del SEPA he generado mis clases en .net a partir de estos ficheros.

En esta ocasión han publicado los diferentes esquemas en http://www.agenciatributaria.es/AEAT.internet/Inicio/Ayuda/Modelos__Procedimientos_y_Servicios/Ayuda_P_G417____IVA__Llevanza_de_libros_registro__SII_/Ayuda_tecnica/Informacion_tecnica_SII/Esquemas/Esquemas.shtml.

Al intentar generarlos con xsd.exe obtengo varios errores:

- Generando SuministroInformacion.xsd (Donde
  D:\Proyectos\IDI\S.I.I\v1.0.0\Documentacion\Esquemas\ es la ruta
  local donde tengo el .xsd)

  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0
  Tools>xsd.exe /c /l:VB
  D:\Proyectos\IDI\S.I.I\v1.0.0\Documentacion\Esquemas\SuministroInformacion.xsd

  Obtengo el error

  Microsoft (R) Xml Schemas/DataTypes support utility [Microsoft (R)
  .NET Framework, Version 4.0.30319.18020] Copyright (C) Microsoft
  Corporation. All rights reserved. Warning: cannot generate classes
  because no top-level elements with complex type were found.

No se muy bien a que se refiere este error. Lo que si que he conseguido es importando el WSDL que también proporciona la Agencia Tributaria y que tiene referenciados los .xsd, usarlos para generar las clases.

No se muy bien que estoy haciendo mal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que `xsd.exe` necesita que se definan elementos para cada tipo en el xsd. Podrias hacerlo a mano pero si son muchas clases es un poco laborioso. Yo te recomiendo que utilices [Xsd2Code](https://xsd2code.codeplex.com/). Es una extensión para visual studio (2008 o 2010).

Una vez instalada abres el visual studio, añades el archivo xsd al proyecto, y con el boton derecho pulsas en el. Seleccionas "Run xsd2code Generation", Generate y te genera una clase con todos los tipos definidos.

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Ha funcionado a la perfección. No conocia la herramienta. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Tengo un problema a la hora de Serializar el objeto. La clase la genera correctamente pero al serializar tanto desde el metodo creado con el Xsd2Code como desde el Serialize con XmlSerializer obtengo este error: No se esperaba el tipo ConexionXSD.SuministroLR.TipoSinDesgloseType. Utilice el atributo XmlInclude o SoapInclude para especificar los tipos que son estáticos.

Comment: Intenta añadiendo `[XmlInclude(typeof(TipoConDesgloseType))]` justo antes de `public partial class TipoSinDesgloseType {...`

Comment: Continua dándome el mismo error. ¿Puede ser por algún tema de los parámetros de Xsd2Code a la hora de generar la clase?

Comment: Diría que no, y normalmente con lo que te he dicho deberia solucionarse, pero intenta volver a generar las clases activando en la parte de `Serialization` GenerateXMLAttributes a true, aunque no estoy muy seguro de que ayude

Comment: No le he dado información a los objetos TipoSinDesgloseType para que no los serializará y funciona. El error esta donde bien me comentabas pero no lo localizo.

Comment: Activando GenerateXMLAttribute ha funcionado. Compararé la clase antes y después para ver que ha cambiado ya que solo fallaba en ese punto.