# Error generando clases vb.Net 2015 desde xsd con xsd2code++

Tags: c#, vb.net, xml, soap, aeat-sii

La Agencia Tributaria española (AEAT) ha publicado una serie de xsd para el nuevo sistema de Suministro Inmediato de Información (SII) que entrará en vigor a partir de Julio de 2017.

[agenciatributaria.es - Link a los esquemas XSD de Aeat](http://www.agenciatributaria.es/AEAT.internet/Inicio/Ayuda/Modelos__Procedimientos_y_Servicios/Ayuda_P_G417____IVA__Llevanza_de_libros_registro__SII_/Ayuda_tecnica/Informacion_tecnica_SII/Esquemas/Esquemas.shtml)

En esta pregunta proponen usar el pluggin xsd2code en lugar del xsd.exe de la línea de comandos.

[stackoverflow.com - Error Generando Clases](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/49357/error-generando-clases-con-xsd)

Tras instalarlo, descargar la licencia trial intento generar la clase SuministroInformacion.xsd pero en el código generado sólo aparecen los Imports.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Xml.Serialization
Imports System.Xml.Serialization
Imports System.Collections
Imports System.Xml.Schema
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Namespace WindowsApplication1
End Namespace
```

Ejecutando el plugin con el fichero RespuestaSuministro.xsd funciona (aparentemente) de forma correcta.

Qué estoy haciendo mal? Alguien está en lo mismo?

Comment: ¿puedes explicar cuál es el resultado que deberías obtener y cuál es el contenido del fichero de prueba que mencionas en tu pregunta?

Comment: La AEAT ofrece 5 ficheros xsd. Todos, excepto el de nombre "SuministroInformacion.xsd", son correctamente interpretados por el pluggin y su archivo designer.vb convenientemente generado.

Comment: Estás seguro de que estás utilizando el archivo xsd correcto? Porque precisamente al responder esa pregunta yo utilicé el `SuministroInformacion.xsd` para probarlo y fue generado correctamente. Por otro lado, existe una version `community` de ese plugin que fue la que yo utilicé, prueba con esa [xsd2code community](https://xsd2code.codeplex.com)

Comment: Lo acabo de descargar y es idéntico al utilizado anteriormente. Me he dado cuenta que el resto de los ficheros incluyen una línea `<import namespace="https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/fact/ws/SuministroInformacion.xsd" schemaLocation="SuministroInformacion.xsd"/>`

Comment: Por otro lado el archivo SuministroInformacion.xsd sólo contiene definición de <complexType> no tiene ningún <element>.

Comment: Efectivamente, no tiene ningun `element` y por eso la herramienta xsd.exe que viene con visual studio no es capaz de generar las clases. Pero con xsd2code si se generan.